# Context Menu and Adding items to textbox c#

Tags: c#, contextmenu

So, what i'm trying to do is this:

---

Have a textbox or item that will add clickable buttons to it. I don't know how to explain it fully, but basically for each file in a folder, add a button that when you click it will print the text inside that textfile.

To attempt to explain it better:
One item on the form, and for every text file in a directory, it will add a contextmenu that has custom options to print it to the textbox.

Sorry if I didn't explain it fully, but I plan to rewrite this in a more reasonable way if needed.

My current code is

```
String path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string s in files)
{
      string file = s.Replace(path + "\\", "").Replace(path + "\\", "").Replace(path + "\\", "");
      richTextBox1.AppendText(file + "\n");
      ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
      cm.MenuItems.Add(file)
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkM7W.png

it prints the text files in the directory fine, but I want to be able to right click them and add the text inside of them to go to the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly you but you can load datas in a txtfile to maybe richTextBox like that:

```
 DialogResult result1 = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
            if (result1 == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                try
                {
                    string line;
                    // Read the file and display it line by line.
                    System.IO.StreamReader file1 =
                       new System.IO.StreamReader(file, true);
                    while ((line = file1.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.LoadFile(file,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                    }
                    richTextBox1.Clear();
                    file1.Close();
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The file could not be read:");

                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you! this is pretty much what I wanted.